# Tried to install golang command but it shows command is not found

Tags: go

I have set my `$GOPATH=$HOME/go` and `$GOROOT=usr/local/go`

I tried to follow this tutorial so that I could do hot reload on my golang webserver

https://github.com/codegangsta/gin

I installed it via

```
go get github.com/codegangsta/gin
```

then I tried to run

```
gin -h
```

> It shows command is not found

I have checked that the library is installed in my `$GOPATH/bin`

What should I do?

Comment: @sinusGob is `$GOPATH/bin` in `$PATH`?

Comment: Just run gin from GOPATH/bin. Where's the problem?

Comment: @zerkms is in $HOME

Comment: @sinusGob ? ...

Comment: @zerkms my apology my $GOPATH=$HOME/go which is $HOME is /Users/username

Comment: Now everytime I have to run $GOPATH/bin/gin ------ , very redundant

Comment: So, is `$GOPATH/bin` in `$PATH`? If it's not - then you need to add it to be able to run `gin` like that

Comment: It's documented on the page you land on when you download Go: https://golang.org/doc/install#tarball

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to add these commands to your shell startup (.bashrc or similar) or do them manually before using gin

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: If you are using a recent version of Go, GOPATH default is $HOME/go, so you are not required to set it. Go is moving away from GOPATH. Just add $HOME/go/bin to PATH.